# Off canvas menu for drupal 6

Tags: 6, routes, navigation

Are there any modules for Drupal 6 that provide an off-canvas menu? My site has mobile users and I want to hide the navigation bar when they view it. I want something like this:

[image: off-canvas responsive menu]

I have searched both Drupal's contributed modules and themes and drupal.SE with no luck: I haven't been able to find any modules or themes with this feature for Drupal 6.

Comment: why the downvote? I've searched everywhere for this and couldn't find it, so I thought it made sense to ask here.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The down-vote is probably because you don't say which modules you tried, and why they didn't suit your use case. Did you search on drupal.org?

Comment: I have searched both Drupal's contributed modules and themes and drupal.stackexchange with no luck.

Comment: you need to adapt your theme - [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/) has a nice example.

Comment: For anyone having the same issue, I couldn't find any modules or themes that do this for Drupal 6, so I ended up just using an external library, you can find a list [here](http://exisweb.net/incredibly-useful-list-of-responsive-navigation-and-menu-patterns)

Comment: Don't worry too much about downvotes (a pitty most downvoters never leave a comment to motivate their downvote, right?). And remember that the rep (points) for 1 upvote of a question (like mine now), compensates for 2,5 downvotes ... Also know that downvoting "questions" is cheap (for the downvoter), it doesn't cost them any rep (points), while downvoting answers costs '-1' points to the downvoter also ... Did you know that?

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap theme

There is the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) base theme for D7 (and even an upcoming D8 version), which bridges the gap between Drupal and the [Bootstrap Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/), with also quite a few (contributed) sub-themes available for it already.

But your question is about D6, for which there is "some" [D6 backport of it available on github](https://github.com/sdmunoz/Drupal-6-Theme-Bootstrap) ... Via Drupal.org there doesn't seem to be any D6 versions, however there "is" [some D5 version](https://www.drupal.org/node/259850) of it also ... Maybe upgrading the D5 version to D6 is another approach to consider?

## Fluid Baseline Grid theme

According to [issue #1855478](https://www.drupal.org/node/1855478) the [Fluid Baseline Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/fbg) is the *Best responsive theme for Drupal 6* ...